# Angular: reactive form. Problema al obtener un dato JSON

Tags: json, angular

Estoy intentando cargar valores en los inputs de un formulario. Lo hago desde una URL y los obtengo en JSON. 
El formulario donde necesito cargar el dato por defecto es:

```
<form [formGroup]="accionForm" class="formulario" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
  <input type="number"   
   name="repeticiones" 
   formControlName="repeticiones"  
   />
</form>
```

Uso esta función que cargo OnInit partiendo de que "madre: any":

```
cargaMadre(){
  const id_tarea = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  this.perioService.getDatosMadre(id_tarea).subscribe(respuesta => {
  this.madre = respuesta;
  this.accionForm.controls['repeticiones'].setValue(this.madre['repeticiones']);
  console.log(this.madre);
  });
}
```

Obtengo los datos que muestro en consola así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en **this.madre['repeticiones']** obtengo valor undefined.

Alguien sabe qué me estoy dejando?

Comment: puedes añadir en tu pregunta la creación del form?

Comment: Creo que sería así: this.madre[0]['repeticiones']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que se ve la respuesta es un array con datos. 
Deberías acceder el primer elemento y ya tendrias el objeto.

```
this.madre = respuesta[0];
```

```
cargaMadre(){
  const id_tarea = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  this.perioService.getDatosMadre(id_tarea).subscribe(respuesta => {
  this.madre = respuesta[0];
  this.accionForm.controls['repeticiones'].setValue(this.madre['repeticiones']);
  console.log(this.madre);
  });
}
```

Comment: Fabuloso. No había pensado que la sintaxis podía ser la de recorrer un arreglo :__)